# Painless script in Elasticsearch to manipulate the score with condition check

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to write a painless script which can be used manipulate the score obtained by Elasticsearch query. It will be conditional check of score and overriding of score. 
Pseudo code of it will be something like

```
          if(_score > 100){
             _score = 99.1;
          }
```

Tried writing the same through below script

```
          {
             "script_score": {
                "script": {
                   "inline": "if(doc[_score].value > 100.00 ){_score=99.1}"
                 }
              }
           }
```

But this is not working getting error as _score variable is read_only.

```
        "lang": "painless",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Variable [_score] is read-only."
         }
```

Any other way we can do that ? Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to return the value: `return 99.1`

Comment: Give us more information. Provide your entire query, index mapping, and data example